# Haskell Crypto.Hash.SHA256 Output

Tags: haskell, cryptography

I'm new to Haskell so forgive me for not understanding the basics.

When using the Crypto.Hash.SHA256 to hash the result is something like below.

```
\159\252\170M\NAK\221\189S\n\191{\197y\t\USUx\143\&3\249\198K}]'\195\nU\154\SI3\199
```

Can anyone explain what the hell it is I'm looking at?

Comment: `"\1\2\3\4\5"` is a representation of the bytes [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. The bytes [97, 98, 99, 100, 101] would show up as `"abcde"`. They’re the printable ASCII interpretation when possible, and octal escape sequences otherwise.

Comment: That's just a string, consisting mostly of unprintable characters - which is to be expected, given that only 95 out of 256 possible byte values correspond to an ASCII character.  The rest of the bytes are represented by an *escape sequence* of some sort: there are abbreviated ones for commonly-used control characters (`\n` for example), names for less common control characters (`\NAK`, etc.), and for everything else just a numeric character code (`\159`, etc.).

Comment: Hmm thanks! I thought that's what it was but the brackets were throwing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the binary representation of the hash. You're probably used to seeing the hexadecimal representation. To get that, import `Data.ByteString.Builder` and call `toLazyByteString . byteStringHex` on it. With the hash in your question, the hexadecimal representation will be `9ffcaa4d15ddbd530abf7bc579091f55788f33f9c64b7d5d27c30a559a0f33c7`.

Comment: Thanks! I had the product (after a base64 conversion) and was able to work backwards and get that exact value but could not figure out the step I was missing. You made the connection for me!